# Get Index of a Dictionary from an array of Dictionaries for a given Key and Value

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<string, string>[]` array, where each element is a `Dictionary<string, string>` with the same Keys and different Values.

How to get the index of the object for a given Key and Value?

For example, if the dictionary array has two elements as:

```
    [0]: {'Key1', 'ValueA}
         {'Key2', 'ValueB}
    [1]: {'Key1', 'ValueC}
         {'Key2', 'ValueD}
```

How to get the index where 'Key2' = 'ValueD'? So, Index result = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following LINQ query which is like a single loop that breaks as soon as possible:

```
int index = dictionaries
    .Select((dict, index) => (dict, index)) // put the dictionary and it's index in a ValueTuple
    .Where(x => x.dict.Any(kv => kv.Key == "Key2" && kv.Value == "ValueD")) // filter by key & value
    .Select(x => x.index) // select the index
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)   // if no dictionary met the condition you want -1 as result
    .First(); // this is safe, you get either a single index or -1 as fallback
```

but note that you are losing the fast lookup capabilities of a dictionary with your approach.

Edit: [Somebody's approac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66333856/284240)h is more efficient, you can combine it with this:

```
int index = dictionaries
    .Select((dict, index) => (dict, index)) // put the dictionary and it's index in a ValueTuple
    .Where(x => x.dict.TryGetValue("Key2", out string value) && value == "ValueD") // filter by key & value
    .Select(x => x.index) // select the index
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1) // if no dictionary met the condition you want -1 as result
    .First(); // this is safe, you get either a single index or -1 as fallback
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!. Based on your comment, is there any other suggestion to handle it improving the dictionary capabilities?

Comment: @Jaume: yes, you could use Somebody's approach. Maybe combine his answer with mine. Because i don't like the two enumerations in the other answers. Edited my answer to show it

Answer (score 2):

In this solution, searching each Dictionary for the given value is O(1) and not O(n) as in the other solutions:

```
string expectedKey = "Key2";
string expectedValue = "ValueD";
var item = array.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TryGetValue(expectedKey , out string value) && value == expectedValue);
if(item == null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("entry wasn't found in any dictionary");
   return;
}
int index = Array.IndexOf(array, item);
```

Comment: I like this approach and adopted it in my answer. But 3 things to note: 1) you will get a `ArgumentNullException` if there was no dictionary found 2) You need two enumerations instead of only one necessary 3) It doesn't compile because `Array.IndexOf` is different than `List<T>.IndexOf`, this compiles: `Array.IndexOf(array, item);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I improved the answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = array.Where(x=>x.Any(y=>y.Key == "Key2" && y.Value == "ValueD")).First();

var index = array.IndexOf(item);
```

Comment: `First` can also accept a filtering delegate.

Comment: yap, just posting a possible solution